# escaping characters in array values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do images swaps on mouseovers in an existing slideshow function. The slideshow function requires me to add values to an array. Within that array I want to call my onMouseOver event handlers, but I believe I am running into an issue with escapable characters.

My attempt:

```
var leftrightslide=new Array()
leftrightslide[0]='<a href="#" onMouseOver="copyspeed=0; document.blah.src=\'images/slides/slideshow_top_01_mo.gif\'" onMouseout="copyspeed=slidespeed"><img src="images/slides/slideshow_top_01.gif" name=\'blah\'></a>';
```

On my MouseOvers, nothing is happening, but when I try to replicate this in just HTML, it works fine. This is what leads me to believe I am not handling the apostrophes in my event handler correctly:

```
<a href="" onMouseOver="document.blah2.src='images/slides/slideshow_top_01_mo.gif';" onMouseout="document.blah2.src='images/slides/slideshow_top_01.gif'"><img src="images/slides/slideshow_top_01.gif" name='blah2'></a>
```

Edit: [Here is a link to a test page with full javascript.](http://www.pachamber.org/www/test/jp.html)

Comment: The first one works just fine for me on Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/BEgRD/

Comment: Thanks for the response Amaan. I have added a link to the page for convenience.

Comment: btw, use `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Comment: Again. The link you've provided animates the images perfectly. Which browser are you using?

Comment: There are two instances of the mouseover. The top slideshow, then the bottom static image. The bottom image swap works just fine, the top does not. Are the images swapping out for you on the top slideshow? I'm using FF, Chrome, and IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that your scripted version is failing because `blah` is not unique. Each instance will need a unique reference name.

Alternatively, pass `this` along with your mouse actions to identify the target.

EDIT

Something like this:

```
<script>
    function over(a){
        a.firstChild.src="bbb.jpg";
    }
    function out(a){
        a.firstChild.src="aaa.jpg";
    }
</script>
<a onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)"><img src="aaa.jpg"/></a>
<a onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out(this)"><img src="aaa.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how to make the name unique in this instance?